# Installing printers drivers in Windows 7 clients with Win server 2003 AD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-7, group-policy, printing

Dears,

I've an issue with installing drivers on windows 7 which keep asking for permission to add the printer driver on other hand i haven't faced this issue with XP clients.

My AD is windows server 2003 I've disabled point and print restrictions from the group policy `User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Printers` and deployed it on windows 7 clients but without any success. same, elevation prompts keep showing up.

Note that i don't have the following option on my AD policy :

`Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers : Point and Print Restrictions`

Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable point and print restrictions in the policy you mentioned above. Open the group policy management console from a machine with Windows Vista/2008 or later and the policy will be there.

As an aside, it's been almost a year that 2003 has been out of support, and almost two years for XP. It's really time to upgrade.

Comment: We're working to change all our PCs to Win7. and the AD of course but until we change the AD I need to fix this issue.

As mentioned i've already disabled point and print restrictions but without any effects on the clients!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [MDMarra](https://serverfault.com/a/738118/183537) and you need to disable ( disallow installation of printers using kernel-mode drivers).
you can read [Allowing Standard Users to Install Network Printers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/7/archive/2011/07/11/allowing-standard-users-to-install-network-printers-on-windows-7-without-prompting-for-administrative-credentials.aspx) and [Configure GPO](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/67e34b3c-8e53-4a38-9e99-92c3dd53e38a/configure-gpo-to-allow-user-install-printer-driver-without-administrative-right?forum=winserverGP)

Answer (score -2):

Thank you guys for helping. I've used RSAT (Microsoft Remote Server Administration Tools) to got what I want and it did solve my issue.

Now the following option is available for me to disable even though with Win Server 2003:
`Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers : Point and Print Restrictions`